Get all pairs by groups in data.table
I want to extract all pairs within groups of a data.table by two columns.
I have the following code:

dt = data.table(g1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                g2 = c(3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6),
                values = letters[1:8])

dt[, .(ind = combn(values, 2, paste0, collapse = "")), by = .(g1, g2)]


But this returns the error
Error in combn(values, 2, paste0, collapse = "") : n < m

The ideal result is some object that contains groups such as:
a,b
c
d,e
f,g
f,h
g,h

If c was not included because there is only one value, that is not a huge concern to me.
Is this possible to get using data.table?
Thanks in advance.
Note:
This answer does what I want for one level.
Generate All ID Pairs, by group with data.table in R

What's the logic? dt[, .(ind = toString(values)), by = .(g1, g2)]?

if (.N > 1) combn(…) else values

You can try the code below
> setnames(dt[, combn(values, min(2, .N), toString), by = .(g1, g2)], "V1", "ind")[]
      g1    g2    ind
   <num> <num> <char>
1:     1     3   a, b
2:     1     4      c
3:     2     5   d, e
4:     2     6   f, g
5:     2     6   f, h
6:     2     6   g, h

or
> dt[, .(ind = combn(values, min(2, .N), toString, FALSE)), by = .(g1, g2)][, ind := unlist(ind)][]
      g1    g2    ind
   <num> <num> <char>
1:     1     3   a, b
2:     1     4      c
3:     2     5   d, e
4:     2     6   f, g
5:     2     6   f, h
6:     2     6   g, h

where min(2, .N) is to rectify the number of selected elements in case that it is less than 2.

This is great. Thanks. For indexing reasons, I also need the ind column to be a string rather than a list. Do you have a suggestion on how to do that quickly?

@SamPassmore see my update

Looks like you want a case handling, either combn or list the values by group.
> dt[, .(ind=if (.N > 1) combn(values, 2, simplify=FALSE) else list(values)), 
+    by=.(g1, g2)]
      g1    g2    ind
   <num> <num> <list>
1:     1     3    a,b
2:     1     4      c
3:     2     5    d,e
4:     2     6    f,g
5:     2     6    f,h
6:     2     6    g,h

You could then subset for lengths equal to two or greater than one.
> dt[, .(ind=if (.N > 1) combn(values, 2, simplify=FALSE) else list(values)), 
+    by=.(g1, g2)][lengths(ind) > 1]
      g1    g2    ind
   <num> <num> <list>
1:     1     3    a,b
2:     2     5    d,e
3:     2     6    f,g
4:     2     6    f,h
5:     2     6    g,h


Sorry, I realise now I didn't make the example complex enough. The reason I am using combn is because I want the output rows to be pairs. I have changed the example so the output won't give pairs by default and some subsets produce multiple rows.

@SamPassmore Do a case handling, combn or list depending on .N.
